# FluidTYPO3: How do I render content from other extensions (news...)?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x, fedext

Actually I found the answer already on this site
[Preferred way to add an extensions into Fluid Powered TYPO3 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202619/preferred-way-to-add-an-extensions-into-fluid-powered-typo3-template)
but I don't get it to work :-(

I have a page template with main content and in the sidebar content from FlexSlider extension and at the bottom I want to render the list view of extension news. So I guess answer 1a from Claus will fit:

> 1a)   create the element in a sys folder and reference it from your Flux form settings then use v:content.render to render it by UID.

but how is that done? How do I reference it from my Flux form?
Has somebody an example code. I couldn't find a tutorial or a documentation...

Thanks for reading and hopefully you have an answer ;-)

Jürgen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it accidentally by fixing another problem:
[Fluid Powered TYPO3 FLUX Fluidcontent - No Output in Frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366315/fluid-powered-typo3-flux-fluidcontent-no-output-in-frontend)
I had to add the file "typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php" with

```
<?php $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['contentRenderingTemplates'] = array('fluidcontentcore/Configuration/TypoScript/');
```

Thanks for help nBar, I used "f.cObject" as workaround.

Now here is my Page/Template code:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="homepage">   
        <flux:grid>
            <flux:grid.row>
                <flux:grid.column colPos="0" colspan="2" name="main" label="Main content"/>
                <flux:grid.column colPos="1" colspan="1" name="logoslider" label="Logo slider"/>
            </flux:grid.row>
            <flux:grid.row>
                <flux:grid.column colPos="2" colspan="3" name="news" label="News"/>
            </flux:grid.row>
        </flux:grid>
    </flux:form>
</f:section>
<f:section name="Main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <v:content.render column="0"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 team_logos">
                <div class="infobox">
                    <v:content.render column="1"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row infobox">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <v:content.render column="2"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</f:section>
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to create a typoscript element and then render it in fluid:

```
lib.rightcolumn = CONTENT
lib.rightcolumn {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList = 42
    where = colPos=1
  }
}

<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.rightcolumn" />
```

Another way is to directly create it in fluid:
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Content/RenderViewHelper.html